# elasticsearch sort by field does not work?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a field used to store string, and the value likes `2015-09-17 17:31:52.3691732`, but I sort by this field, it does not work.

Here is some response

```
{
  "time":"2015-09-17 17:31:52.3691732",
  "ti":"b18265be-67a0-4fa7-974f-8198edd1252a"},
  "sort":["52.3691732"]
}
```

If es only sort by the last ten bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your date field as string then Elasticsearch will break it up into individual terms:

`2015-09-17 17:31:52.3691732`
will become

```
2015
09
17
17
31
52.3691732
```

When you sort descending then `52.3691732` will appear first (due to the leading `5`).

if you want to sort this field as a date - you'll need to define it as a **date** in your mapping.